# How to solve "Your Requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a new Laravel project using composer but I keep getting this error message. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```php
  - laravel/framework[v8.40.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
  - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
  - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.40 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.40.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

```
- C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

[Command Prompt screenshot of the project creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwPmN.png)

Comment: Here is the answer,

- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.40 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.40.0, ..., 8.x-dev]


You need to check the base composer.json file to check if any of your packages are using older dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to uncomment the extension `extension = fileinfo` in the php.ini file from the source folder. Then delete projectx dir. Finally, re-run laravel new projectx as per your screenshot.

If you have already uncomment `extension = fileinfo` in php.ini and it doesn't work. You might need to grant administrator permissions to be able to execute the changes:

To grant these permissions you have to do the following: Note: This for windows 10.

1. It is located in the file to grant the permission "c:/xampp/php/php.ini". And for your case its - C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini
2. Right click on the file and click on properties.
3. Security.
4. Click on the Edit button.
5. Click on each of the group or user names and at the bottom where it says Permissions for authenticated users, and then check full control.

In this way permission is granted and now if the changes to the file are saved.